# Windows 10 - RDP with local computer credentials

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I thought I used to be able to connect to remote computers and use ".\" in order to use local credentials of the target computer. However, in Windows 10, it's populating MY computer name, instead of the target computer name. How do I get it to fill in the target computer name?

Comment: It will not do this automatically. You should be able to do this with `.\ ` preceding the username. If this does not work, you will have to know the computername. If you only know the IP, the computername can be found by pinging the remote machine with the `-a` flag. Ex. `ping -a 10.10.10.10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the plot thickens. In other Windows editions, when I used to do ".\", it would populate the target computer name. For some reason, Windows 10 is populating my computer name.

However, **this still works**. Windows isn't showing the local computer name anywhere, but I have been successfully connecting to non-domain computers with local credentials. Why did they design it like this? It's so confusing.

[Windows 10 RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNmyy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It will not do this automatically. You should be able to do this with `.\` preceding the username. If this does not work, you will have to know the computername. If you only know the IP, the computername can be found by pinging the remote machine with the `-a` flag. Ex. `ping -a 10.10.10.10`.